# Sum of digits of a number raised to a power

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f$ be a function such that it takes a non-negative integer in decimal representation and gives the sum of its digits raised to $2001$ (e.g. $f(327)=3^{2001} + 2^{2001} + 7^{2001}$).
Prove that for any $x$ the set $\{f(x),f(f(x)),f(f(f(x))),\dots\}$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

There is a constant $C$ such that $f(n)<n$ for all $n>C$. Suppose $n$ has $d=\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor+1$ digits. Then, $f(n)\leq d\cdot 9^{2001}$. We want to solve
$$
n\geq d\cdot9^{2001}=\lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor 9^{2001}
$$
Because $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac n{\log_{10}n}=\infty$, we know there is a $C$ such that this is satisfied for every $n>C$.

Now, we know that the sequence $(f^k(n))_{k\geq 0}$ is decreasing until it drops below $C$ (say at $k=l$). From then on ($k\geq l$), there are only $C$ possible values it can take, so it has a period of at most length $C$. Now, $(f^{k+l})_{k\geq 0}$ is periodic, so it will only reach a finite number of different values. Also, it only takes a finite amount of steps to drop below $C$, so the total number of different values $(f^k(n))_{k\geq 0}$ will take is finite.